# Best way to design a module so that its state is easily mocked and tested

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two require modules:

**state.js**

```
define(function () {
    var stateObj = {hello:"test!"};

    return {
        getObj: function () {  
            return stateObj; 
        }
    };
});
```

**main.js**

```
define(['state'],function (global) {
    var privateFn = global.getObj()

    return {
        getHello: function () {
            if(privateFn.hello == "test!")
               //do someoperation
        },
        changeState : function() {
             //changes the privateFn state
        }
    };
});
```

`state` module provides the object to the `main` module, which it uses for internal state storage. The reason for keeping separate module for `main`'s internal state is for easy testing, so that in my test cases, I can inject a fake `state` module and check how the `main` module works.

Since I'm new to js world, the approach that I have taken here is correct or not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a downvote, then it's probably because it's difficult to answer in a definitive way. In fact, I'm looking at the code, and not even sure what you are asking. Here are some thoughts from me, but be aware that others might very well disagree.

Your state is a singleton, so it should be easy enough to test. Let's say your `changeState` method above looks like this:

```
changeState: function (key, value) {
    privateFn[key] = value;
}
```

Then you can test it by including both `state` and `main`, and then call `main.changeState` and see if the `state` updated as expected:

```
main.changeState('foo', 'bar');
expect(state.foo).toBe('bar');
```

Other ways to do this (in case `state` is not a singleton), is to actually expose the state on your `main`. This would normally be done by prefixing it with underscore so it's considered private (a naming convention, it isn't actually private). Then, in your test, you can "cheat" and look directly at the state.

```
main.changeState('foo', 'bar');
expect(main._state.foo).toBe('bar');
```

Another way, is through dependency injection (this is popular in the angular world). That means `main` needs to be a Factory of some sort, or a class. If you're from a java world, then a class probably makes the most sense:

```
// Some other file where both main.js and state.js is imported
var main = new Main({
    state: state
});
```

So the `main.js` does not import anything on its own.

I hope this answered your question.

While I'm at it (typing): be careful with your naming. `global` usually refers to `window` (so does `root`), so having `global` refer to your state is very confusing. Give it the same name: `state`. Also your `privateFn` refers to an object and not a function (as the `Fn` postfix would imply). Also confusing.

A third thing, which I'm not sure everyone would agree with me on, is that "state" should refer to the state itself. What it is here, is a wrapper. Kind of like a `Model` from BackboneJS (where `attributes` would be what I call `state`). It's important to distinguish between the two:

1. a wrapper, exposing helpful methods and other stuff
2. and the actual data (usually an object).

The actual data can usually (if not always) be converted into JSON and sent stored on a server. Unlike in Java (I think?), your state should at all times be easy to separate from its class/wrapper. The wrapper can (should) depend on the data, but the data should definitely not depend on its wrapper.

---

**Edit**

It just dawned on me, that maybe you meant for the `main.js` to be the wrapper of the data (and the only wrapper). If that's the case, then I'd construct it differently. I'd just have a single file. Something like:

```
function modelFactory (options) {
    var state = options.state || {};

    // Useful methods...
    return {
        get: function (key) {
            return state[key];
        },
        set: function (key, value) {
            state[key] = value;
            // Maybe trigger some change event for others to listen for
        },
        toJSON: function () {
            return JSON.stringify(state);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then to test it, you can do

```
var model = modelFactory({
    state: {foo: 'bar'}
});

expect(model.get('foo')).toBe('bar');

model.set('hello', 'world');
expect(model.get('hello')).toBe('world');
```

What I described above, is the basics of a `Backbone.Model`.

Comment: It was just as a comment to his own comment on the answer. :-)